# text selection with no titlebar will cause crush

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I hide the titlebar like below and it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

However when I long click and start word selection in webView or editText, the application will crush.

```
: E/AndroidRuntime(30416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: Process: com.example.aaa, PID: 30416
: java.lang.NullPointerException
:   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:302)
:   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
:   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getActionBarThemedContext(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:210)
:   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:195)
:   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:359)
:   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2441)
:   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2366)
:   at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
:   at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
:   at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
:   at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4585)
:   at android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode(Editor.java:1619)
:   at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:883)
:   at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8681)
:   at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18725)
:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think this is because word selection use the space of `Titlebar`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: send logs where it actually crashing...

Comment: NullPointerException :P this line is not enough post complete log cat 20 to 30 lines whatever you are getting :)

Comment: sorry I post my logcat message

Answer (score 0):

is Your Activity extends ActionbarActivity.
if "yes " then you need to write custom theme.

Comment: yes I extends ActionbarActivity. and I tryed to use <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> but it still crush. ( in this case I should use Fragment Activity instead)